# Ruby include? with YAML array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, yaml, conditional-statements

I have a config YAML file with the following array:

```
EMAILS: ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com']
```

And then I want to search inside this YAML array for a particular string, say "email1@example.com".

I use the following ruby code:

```
if CONFIG[:EMAILS].include?("email1@example.com")
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

However, this always returns false.

I can `PUTS` the `CONFIG[:EMAIL]` array fine.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your ruby code assumes that the YAML has already been loaded into a hash. How did that happen?

Comment: Can you post the output of `CONFIG[:EMAILS]` please? and how you parse the yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a symbol, while the YAML hash uses strings as keys. This should work:

```
if CONFIG['EMAILS'].include?("email1@example.com")
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

Which, by the way, is equivalent to simply

```
return CONFIG['EMAILS'].include?("email1@example.com")
```

Comment: The `return` part is completely redundant if you have this as your last line of a method. Presumably this line would be given the previous behavior was to exit regardless of the condition.

Comment: In both cases it would exit the function, so if there was code after that it wouldn't have been executed.

Comment: Sure. It's still a big "if" and therefore *not* equivalent in all circumstances.

Comment: I was pretty clear that *if* that was the last line, then the `return` is not required. This is basic Ruby behavior. It is not controversial. Under all circumstances where it's the last line, it is equivalent.